# Angular child component does not detect change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-changedetection

I am updating product object from parent component. Somehow the child component does not detect the change and does not update it.

**product.ts**

```
export interface Product { 
    productId: number;
    productName: string;
    lastUpdated: string;
    orders: Array<Order>
}
```

**order.ts:**

```
export interface Order { 
    orderId: number;
    payments: Array<Payment>
}
```

**payment.ts:**

```
export interface Payment { 
    paymentId: number;
    amount: Array<number>
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<product-details [(product)]="product1" (refreshProduct)="refreshProduct()"></product-details>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
product1: Product = null;

refreshProduct() {
      this.sub = this.productService.getTheLatestOrders().subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.product1.lastUpdated = data.lastUpdated;
          this.product1.orders.forEach(order => {
            let latestOrderData = data.orders.find(d => d.orderId == order.orderId);
            if(latestOrderData) {
              order.payments = latestOrderData.payments;
            }
          });
          // this.product1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.product1)); --> It works if I add this
      });
    }
  }
```

**product-details.component.html (child component)**

```
<button id="refresh" name="refresh" (click)="refresh()" />
Last Updated : {{product.lastUpdated}}

<ng-container *ngFor="let order of product.orders">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let payment of order.payments">
             {{payment.date}} - {{payment.amount}} 
      </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

**product-details.component.ts (child component)**

```
@Input('product') product: Product;
@Output() refreshProduct = new EventEmitter<any>();

refresh() {
  this.refreshProduct.emit();
}
```

I tried to declare `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` explicitly but no luck.

As mentioned in the code, if I add `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.product1));` then it works. So it seems that I need to create a new object so change detection work. I think I can use spread operator (object.assign) to make sure it creates a new object. However, I am not sure how to update the product inside refreshProduct() method using spread operation.

I think the code will look like:

```
this.product1 = {...this.product1, 
            lastUpdated: data.lastUpdated,
            orders: .... // --> Not sure how to loop through orders and update the payments

          };
```

EDIT: I think I managed to do it.

```
this.product1 = {...this.product1, 
            lastUpdated: data.lastUpdated,
            orders: this.product1.orders.map((order) => {
                     let updatedOrder = data.orders.find(o => o.orderId == order.orderId);  
                     return {...order, order.payments: updateOrder.payments};

                    })
          };
```

Please let me know if there is any better solution available.

Comment: remove `changeDetection: ...Strategy.OnPush` from `product-details.component`. It would be a problem to you to work with onPush strategy, in case you don't follow the immutability principles

Comment: Thanks @Andrei . I thought it would be the case however product-details.component does not have changeDetection declared so I assume it is using the default strategy.

Comment: you can read about change detection in detail here https://jagjeets.medium.com/using-angular-change-detection-effectively-f69d6a493c35

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this:

```
refreshProduct() {
      let temp: Product = {};
      this.sub = this.productService.getTheLatestOrders().subscribe(
        (data) => {
          temp.lastUpdated = data.lastUpdated;
          temp.orders.forEach(order => {
            let latestOrderData = data.orders.find(d => d.orderId == order.orderId);
            if(latestOrderData) {
              order.payments = latestOrderData.payments;
            }
          });
          this.product1 = temp;
      });
    }
  }
```

In this way every time it will assign the updated value to product.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to preserve any product changes the user has made when refreshing the product. Example: If they have changed the name in Product1 then the change should remain. In your answer, it will overwrite the name with the data received from API.